# boot() generating an error on replacement - R

Tags: r, replace, p-value, statistics-bootstrap

I've written a couple of functions for retrieving statistics (coefficients and p-values) from an lm object, to be bootstrapped upon. The coefficient one works; the p-value one is failing with error:

```
Error in boot(data = data, statistic = bs_p, R = 1000) : 
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

I now believe the error is related to the inclusion of a factor variable.  Attempting to recreate the problem with easily reproducible data.

```
    L3 <- LETTERS[1:3]
    data <- data.frame(cbind(x = 20:69, y = 1:50), fac = sample(L3, 50, replace = TRUE))
    bs_p <- function (data, i) {
      d <- data[i,]
      fit <- lm (d$y~d$x*d$fac, data=d)
      return(summary(fit)$coefficients[,4])
    }
    bt <- boot(data=data, statistic=bs_p, R=1000)
```

The class "numeric" values returned from each of these appears to be in exactly the same format, to my beginner's eye... but I'm guessing it isn't?  I have also cleared the returned bt bootstrap object before running the next function, but that did not solve it.  How could I best retrieve boot-strapped p-values?  Thanks for any thoughts.  (Running R 3.0.1 on Mac OSX.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if you can bootstrap `p-values` from `lm` model (but the solution is provided for that) . In your `bs` or `bs_r` function, you can remove `d$` on the right hand side of `fit` since you already defined data d. Here is the example using mtcars data :

```
library(boot)

bs <- function(mtcars, i) {
  d <- mtcars[i,]
  fit <- lm (mpg~drat+wt, data=d)
  return(coef(fit))
}
bt <- boot(data=mtcars, statistic=bs, R=1000)

bt

ORDINARY NONPARAMETRIC BOOTSTRAP


Call:
boot(data = mtcars, statistic = bs, R = 1000)


Bootstrap Statistics :
     original      bias    std. error
t1* 30.290370  0.54284222    7.494441
t2*  1.442491 -0.07260619    1.393801
t3* -4.782890 -0.09804271    1.000838
```

Here is the p-values for bootstrapped p-values from `lm`.

```
bs_r <- function(mtcars, i) {
  d <- mtcars[i,]
  fit <- lm (mpg~drat+wt, data=d)
  return(summary(fit)$coefficients[,4])
}
bt1 <- boot(data=mtcars, statistic=bs_r, R=1000)

ORDINARY NONPARAMETRIC BOOTSTRAP


Call:
boot(data = mtcars, statistic = bs_r, R = 1000)


Bootstrap Statistics :
        original       bias     std. error
t1* 2.737824e-04 4.020024e-03 0.0253248217
t2* 3.308544e-01 7.108738e-02 0.2960776146
t3* 1.589075e-06 5.405459e-05 0.0005540412
```

Comment: Thank you!  I edited my question above, as I am coming to realize that this error may have to do with the factor variable I was including in the interaction term.  I'm now working on reliably recreating the problem -- sometimes boot seems to choke on the factor variable, sometimes it doesn't.  I'm accepting your helpful answer re. syntax, and will open a new question if I can recreate a factor-related issue reliably.  Thanks again.

Comment: I don't think so. The code still works when I replace say `wt` with `as.factor(cyl)`. Please use `set.seed` for reproducibility when you decide to post the next question using `sample`.